# Detect with python script if a blend file has packed images

Tags: python

I'm trying to know if a blend file contains images and if it contains to unpack the images out to the directory.
So just before I'm running this line:

```
bpy.ops.file.unpack_all(method='USE_ORIGINAL')
```

to ask if this blend file is with packed images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`Image.packed_file`**](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Image.html?highlight=packed_file#bpy.types.Image.packed_file111)

Look at the value of the [`Image.packed_file`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Image.html?highlight=packed_file#bpy.types.Image.packed_file111) property. Will be `None` if not packed.

Console test.

```
>>> for i in bpy.data.images:
...     i.name, i.packed_file
...     
('3cb598.jpg', bpy.data.images['3cb598.jpg']...PackedFile)
('3b17ebcf9eb9.jpg', None)
('huge.49.247445.JPG', bpy.data.images['huge.49.247445.JPG']...PackedFile)
('Render Result', None)

>>>
```

Comment: Thanx @batFINGER :) it's exactly what I need.