# How to get pack project status

Tags: python, packed-data

I was wondering if there was a way to get the status of the project, whether it's Packed or not in python, and in the case how to get that information, I checked the api but with little success.
Not have idea how to read current status by python Like to :
current project pack status get 
About pack , unpack etc.
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93412/detect-with-python-script-if-a-blend-file-is-packed-with-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is stored under the

```
bpy.data.use_autopack
```

value.

True: Autopack is enabled, False: Autopack is disabled.

Documentation is https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.use_autopack